# Magento is not sending emails of new orders

Tags: sales-order, order-email, magento-cron, email-queue

Magento is not sending emails when there are new orders neither when you comment on the order. 
Invoice, credit memo, shipping and contact us are working perfectly. 
Queued emails are in core email queues database with posted date NULL. 
Used to be able to get it working by editing order.php but it's not working anymore. 
Cron job is there but not sure if I need to change anything in cron.php
Spent whole night trying to figure it out and even contacted hosting support, nothing.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Specify your magento version

Comment: if you are using magento 1 version, please install aoe scheduler 
https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler
and look at the cron jobs, investigate them .

Comment: 1.9.3.6 is there another option? Dont want to wait for 15 minutes until i get an order confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded it to 1.9.3.7 and changed code in order.php. It worked. Probably some code was broken along the way.